# Toggle Function Not Working - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an interesting problem. I received help with a function that once a menu trigger is clicked, checks to see if a class has been added to a div and then either displays or fades out. Problem is the function only seems to run once.

Below is the snippet of what I have made.

```js
$(function() {

    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        if( $('.mainNav').hasClass('showMainNav')) {
            $('.mainNav').fadeOut(100, function() {
                $('.mainNav').removeClass('showMainNav');
            });
        } else {
            $('.mainNav').addClass('showMainNav');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
nav {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-fixedWidth {
    width: 95vw;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.logo-and-trigger {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
    align-self: center;
}

.trigger {
    display: none;
}

.mainNav {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.mainNav>li {
    padding: 23px 14.6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    &:nth-child(6) {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    
}

.mainNav>li>a {
    @extend .navText;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1046px) {
    
    .logo-and-trigger {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .trigger {
        display: flex;
        align-self: center;
        color: black;

        .fa.fa-bars {
            font-size: 35px;
            color:#ccc;
        }
    }
    
    .mainNav {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vw;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-top: 137px;
        background-color: white;
        display: none;
    }
    
    .showMainNav {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .mainNav>li {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 10px;

    }    

    .mainNav>li>a {
        font-size: 21px;
        color: rgb(102, 160, 253);
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 28px;
        text-decoration: none;
    } 
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
            <div class="nav-fixedWidth">
               <div class="logo-and-trigger">
                   <p class="logo">Logo Here</p>
                   <div class="trigger">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   </div>
               </div>
                <ul class="mainNav">
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#meetDrive">Meet Drive</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#usingDrive">Using Drive</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#forWork">For Work</a></li>
                    <li class="navText"><a href="#Help">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

made, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where you have defined `showMainNav` class.

Comment: @bhansa -- .....in the media query. At 1046px a little hamburger menu appears and then regular .mainNav goes display: none with a series of other changes

Comment: `fadeOut()` hides the element, so when you add the class again, it's still hidden.  You need to add `fadeIn()` or `.show()` when adding the class back.

Comment: It's clearer if you remove all the css and put some text against the `fa-` icon in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fadeOut` is adding CSS property `"display:none"`. If you want to keep the animation, you need to do something like this.

```
$(function() {

 $('.trigger').click(function() {
    if( $('.mainNav').hasClass('showMainNav')) {
        $('.mainNav').fadeOut(100, function() {
            $('.mainNav').removeClass('showMainNav');
        });
    } else {
        $('.mainNav').addClass('showMainNav').css("display","");
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: THIS WORKED! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery fadeOut method will generate display:none on inline css. Do remember that inline css is stronger than class defined.

you can use below code

```
$(function() {    
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        if( $('.mainNav').hasClass('showMainNav')) {
            $('.mainNav').fadeOut(100, function() {
                $('.mainNav').removeClass('showMainNav');
            });
        } else {
            $('.mainNav').fadeIn(100, function() {
                $('.mainNav').addClass('showMainNav');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

or simply use jQuery toggle method

```
$(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $('.mainNav').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
            if( $('.mainNav').hasClass('showMainNav')) {
                $('.mainNav').removeClass('showMainNav');
            } else {
                $('.mainNav').addClass('showMainNav');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a toggle code for your classes, use the existing jquery function [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").on("click", function() {
        $(".mainNav").toggleClass("showMainNav");
    });
});
```

Demo: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tb4khmuk/)

Comment: The problem with that is I want the display:block to be the first action and then a fade-out as it is removed.

Comment: Put the display:block as default in your css and then toggle.